# Apple blocks Xamarin application on iOS using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, xamarin, sdwebimage

After adding Xamarin.SDWebImage Apple blocks the application.

> > Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:
>
> - LinkPresentation.framework
> - QuickLookThumbnailing.framework
>
> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because
>   it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.
>
> Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of
>   this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer
>   account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.

here is packages I use :

```
  ....
 <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Connectivity" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Build.Download" version="0.4.10" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics" version="4.0.5.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging" version="2.0.8.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core" version="4.0.13.1" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CrashReporting" version="2.0.0.5" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.InstanceID" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Google.iOS.Maps" version="2.5.0" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xamarin.SDWebImage" version="4.4.7" targetFramework="xamarinios10" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Try to setting linker setting to `Link Framework SDKs Only` and if that doesn't work, try adding this to the Additional mtouch arguments input in your project:
`--linksdkonly --linkskip=LinkPresentation --linkskip=QuickLookThumbnailing`

Comment: I use >> Link Framework SDKs Only << and following mtouch arguments : --registrar:static -v -v -v -v ... Okay I will try another arguments you mentioned , but will it work for QuickLookThumbnailing.famwork ?? @Saamer

Comment: It should work for both

Comment: did it end up working?

Comment: I did load image from url manually

Comment: Hmm.. Funny story, I just faced the issue in one of my apps, and when I google'd the question, it got me here. And then I followed the steps and my changes actually worked for me :)

Comment: @Saamer add as an answer what you did to fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

So I just had this issue a few days ago on a new project, getting a rejection telling me that my  app uses or references the following non-public APIs: - LinkPresentation.framework & QuickLookThumbnailing.framework.

And they warned me:

> Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of
>   this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer
>   account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.

So this was very serious. But they also provided me with more information that was useful:

> If you do not have access to the libraries' source, you may be able to
>   search the compiled binary using the "strings" or "otool" command line
>   tools. The "strings" tool can output a list of the methods that the
>   library calls and "otool -ov" will output the Objective-C class
>   structures and their defined methods. These tools can help you narrow
>   down where the problematic code resides. You could also use the "nm"
>   tool to verify if any third-party libraries are calling these APIs.

So, I opened my solution Visual Studio-> Right click on iOS project->View Archives->Right Click on my archive that I published and "Reveal in Finder"->Right click on XCARCHIVE file and "View package contents". In there I saw a number of folders that I could use those command line tools on.

Then, I went back to my Visual Studio and in my project options I set linker setting to Link Framework SDKs Only, and added this to the Additional mtouch arguments input in my iOS Project Option: `--linksdkonly --linkskip=LinkPresentation --linkskip=QuickLookThumbnailing`.

Then I rearchived, and found the size of the new archive to be much smaller. I also compared the package contents of both the XCARCHIVE files, and I found that the msyms folder of the newer archive had a lot fewer subfolders too.

In my response to the rejection I told them that I had archived the application incorrectly, and I will resubmit the app with a new archive. After I resubmitted the app using the new archive, they approved and published the app in just a few hours.